# What are pivot tables in layman terms?

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, phalcon

I think my problem calls for a pivot table but I want to be clear before spending a huge amount of time trying to implement. I have not yet used pivot tables for any projects.

I have a new project that contains multiple "kits" that have common "parts" among them and in some cases a part can be interchanged with those for another kit. Likewise not all parts are compatible with one another.

Rather than having to create some nightmarish SQL query I was hoping to essentially build a table that would store compatibility information to make cross referencing a simple SQL query.

**Example:**

```
SELECT kitID FROM crossRefTable WHERE partA, partC and partE are true.
```

**Or for example:**

```
SELECT partID FROM crossRefTable WHERE partA and partE are true.
```

(Yes, the SQL queries are exmple only for stressing the point)

I am not sure that the "**belongTo**" and "**hasMany**" necessarily apply here or if so how would that be implemented?

Coding is in **PhalconPHP** using **MongoDB**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have 23 kits and 512 distinct parts. How do you define that kit 1 uses parts A, B, and C while kit 2 uses parts A, D, E, and F? A pivot table is a good solution for defining the relationship between each kit and its parts. Once you have a Kits table, a Parts table and a KitParts table, then you can join the three together for easy queries. Once joins become second nature to you, they're actually a pleasure to work with.

In terms of PhalconPHP, `hasMany` and `belongsTo` ([note it has an s](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#defining-relationships)) combined with a pivot table is a great solution. In the pivot table you'd reference a kit's id and a part's id.

Let's say the user is currently viewing a list of all kits and they click a specific kit, now you'd like to display all the parts is contains. Your example is almost exactly the same situation as the [Phalcon manual shows](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#relationships-between-models). But in terms of how I'd personally write it, I'd take more the following route:

(**Note:** this is all untested and I haven't touched phalcon in a few months)

```
//Use your BaseModel to take some of the weight off your Models.
//Nobody likes dirty Models, just ask Victoria's Secret. :p
//BaseModels are a good place to add your own methods,
//that way all models have access to them.
class BaseModel extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
}

class Kits extends Basemodel
{
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->hasMany('id', 'KitParts', 'kit_id', array(
        'foreignKey' => array(
        'message' => 'Kit cannot be deleted because it\'s used by KitParts'
        )
        ));
    }
}

//Pivot table
class KitParts extends BaseModel
{
    public $id;
    public $kit_id;   //primary key used in Kits.id
    public $part_id;  //primary key used in Parts.id
    $this->belongsTo('kit_id', 'Kits', 'id');
    $this->belongsTo('part_id', 'Parts', 'id');
}

class Parts extends BaseModel
{
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->hasMany('id', 'KitParts', 'part_id', array(
        'foreignKey' => array(
        'message' => 'Part cannot be deleted because it\'s used by KitParts'
        )
        ));
    }
}
```

Then to display all parts for a particular kit, you'd write:

```
$kit = Kits::findFirst(123);//Find record with id = 123
foreach ($kit->kitParts as $kitPart)
{
    echo htmlentities($kitPart->parts->name), "<br>\n";
}
```

You could also add a method to your Kits class to make life easier:
(Again, this is untested... refer to the [documentation](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html) if something is wrong.)

```
//Add this as a method to the "Kits" class
public function getParts()
{
    $results = array();
    foreach ($this->kitParts as $kitPart)
    {
        $results[] = $kitPart->parts;
    }
    return $results;
}
```

Then you'd do:

```
$kit = Kits::findFirst(123);//Find record with id = 123
$parts = $kit->getParts();
if(count($parts) > 0)
{
    echo "<strong>Parts</strong><br>\n";
    foreach($parts as $part)
    {
        echo htmlentities($part->name),"<br>\n";
    }
}else{
    echo "No parts to show.<br>\n";
}
```